# How to to set an alarm on SWI-Prolog?

Tags: timer, window, prolog, alarm, swi-prolog

I'm trying to make something that print something on screen after 5000 miliseconds.
I Was using this code, and after 5 seconds the Prolog shuts down.
I have this code to compile:

```
:- use_module(library(time)).

alarm:-
   alarm(5, writeln(ouch), Id, [remove(true)]).
```

Comment: Which SWI-Prolog version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.6.6 version

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko Wich version you using of Prolog? Thanks

Comment: @PedroSilva "SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.2.6)" on Linux.

Comment: On SWI-Prolog 7.1.16 running on Mac OS X 10.9, I only get the atom `ouch` printed after calling the `alarm/0` predicate and after the five seconds passed if I call another predicate at the top-level. Adding a call to `flush_output/0` after the call to `writeln/1` doesn't solve the issue. Is this the behavior that you're observing? In which operating-system?

Answer (score 2):

The alarm mechanism works by sending a signal (see thread_signal/2).  Signals are only trapped reliably if Prolog is nicely running a goal.  Some long running foreign goals explicitly query for pending signals.  Some blocking goals handle them too, but this depends on the OS.

A more reliable way to handle timing is by using threads.  For example:

```
?- thread_create((sleep(5), writeln(ouch)), _, [detached(true)]).
true.

?- outch
```

Alternatively, you have to make sure that the thread issuing the alarm is in a state where it can receive the signal.  The toplevel is not (on all platforms).  AFAIK, sleep/1 is.  So, you can make sure that the thread is running (for example):

```
sleep :- sleep(1000), sleep.
```